# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't boot after recent kernel updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, kernel, updates

I have a dual boot HP laptop with Windows and Ubuntu 18.04. I am currently using kernel version **5.3.0-62-generic** but with the past two kernel updates Ubuntu crashes when I start those versions of Ubuntu kernel image.

I have to go to Advanced options to boot previous kernel version.

[image: Kernel versions I have]

I thought with a new update this would get fixed on its own. But it still crashes. Thanks for your help.

HP Laptop -

- Product Name **HP Laptop 15-bs1xx**
- Product Number **4AG16PA#ACJ**
- BIOS Version **F.34**

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] password for devans:
F.34
```

```
$ free -h
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8G        2.3G        271M        239M       1.2G       1.0G
Swap:         2.0G        109M        1.9G
```

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

[image: Laptop information]

Not able to boot to Ubuntu after bios update.

Even switching order doesn't help

[image]

Edit after BIOS update -

So after the bios update the GRUB menu doesn't come up. The system automatically boots to Windows. I went in boot option to manually boot Ubuntu but that gives boot device failed. Adding images to the following -

Boot menu

[image: Boot Menu]

Ubuntu boot option

[image: Ubuntu Boot Option]

Boot device fail

[image: Boot Device Fail]

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113585/discussion-on-question-by-devans-somani-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-boot-after-recent-k). Please continue there as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP Notebook 15-bs164tu

You have a very old BIOS version F.34.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F.65 Rev A, from Jan 10, 2020, and it can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-bs100-laptop-pc/16851388/model/21833346).

For BIOS install help, see [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**/swapfile**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Well... although I believe that there's just a setting in the new BIOS... let's start with the basics... and check your file system.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #2:**

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it's all working again... and it's working with the latest kernel, and the new BIOS.